# Counting - $9$ digit number consisting of $5$ odd and $4$ even digits, not sure how to do the 2nd step

Tags: combinatorics

So I'm trying to calculate the total number of $9$-digit combinations consisting of $5$ odds and $4$ evens ($1$ through $9$).

I calculated it as $5^5 \cdot 4^4$. The order of even and odds don't matter. I was wondering, is there another step I need to do to factor that odd and even numbers can be in any positions?

Comment: If you are interested in constructing a $9$-digit number, then the order of the digits matters since $235714968$ is different from $862413579$.  Therefore, we need to choose the positions of the odd digits.

Comment: When order matters, is there a way for me to find the total number of all possible positions the 5 odd numbers can be placed in? I can manually write it all out but I was wondering if there was some sort to formula or quicker method

Comment: The number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements is given by $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$ In this case, you need to count the number of ways of selecting five of the nine positions for the odd numbers.  The symbol $\binom{n}{k}$ is read "$n$ choose $k$".  See this article on [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: Your use of the word combinations in the first sentence of your question is misleading if you want the number of nine-digit positive integers with five odd digits and four even digits.  You should say positive integers, numbers (a bit less precise), or permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is **incorrect.**

---

You calculated *the number of all 9-digit combinations starting with $5$ odd numbers and $4$ even numbers*.

This is not what the question is asking. For example, you only count $111112222$, but not $111121222$

---

To solve the problem, think about constructing a $9$ digit number in two steps:

1. First, select the positions of the odd numbers.
2. Then, pick the odd numbers for the odd positions, and even numbers for the even positions.

Comment: The digit 0 needs a special treatment (it can not occur as the first digit).

Comment: @Muralidharan Not true. Please read the original question.

Comment: I can find all the different positions that the 5 odd numbers can be placed in and multiple that by my original answer. Is that correct? Is there quicker way then having to write out all the combinations myself? That's what Im trying to figure out.

Comment: @KJang9402 You don't have to find all the positions. Think about **choosing** the positions, and think about how many ways you can *choose* them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another step I need to do to factor [in] that even and odd numbers can be in any positions?

Yes, we must choose which positions are occupied by odd numbers.  The number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements is 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
where the symbol $\binom{n}{k}$ is read "$n$ choose $k$" and $n!$ is read "$n$ factorial".  By definition, $0! = 1$ and $n!$ is the product of the first $n$ positive integers when $n$ is a positive integer.

In this case, we need to choose five of the nine positions for the odd integers, which can be done in 
$$\binom{9}{5} = \frac{9!}{5!4!} = \frac{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5!}{5! \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 126$$
ways. Notice that choosing the positions of the odd integers forces us to fill the remaining four positions with even integers.

Since there are $5$ choices for each of the five odd digits and $4$ choices for each of the $4$ even digits, there are
$$\binom{9}{5}5^54^4$$
nine-digit positive integers with five odd digits and four even digits that can be constructed using the digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$.

For background, you may want to read about

- the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)
- [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)
- [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)
- [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is **incorrect**

---

As the question asks about **combinations**

Let us define $a_i$ as number of times the digit $i$ has been taken.

$\therefore a_1 + a_3 + a_5 + a_7 + a_9 = 5$

$a_2 + a_4 + a_6 + a_8 + a_0 = 4$

We have $\binom{9}{5}$ ways for the first statement and $\binom{9}{4}$ for the second

$\therefore$ Total number of combinations = $\binom{9}{5}\binom{9}{4} = 15876$